# aiogram, ошибка отправки фото по FSM

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Пытаюсь настроить обработку события присылаемого фото для отправки его в чат
Идея такая, При получении фотографии заполнять подпись к нему и отправлять в supergroup
Попробовал через fsm передать значения для отправик фото, бьюсь уже неделю, чет не доходит до меня
В чем может быть ошибка?

```
# Обработка присылаемого фото
class WaitPhoto(StatesGroup):
    waiting_photo = State()
    # waiting_photo_commit = State()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def photo_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id  # file ID загруженной фотографии
    await state.update_data(file_id=file_id)
    # print(type(file_id))
    # file_id1 = pic.photo
    button_phone = types.KeyboardButton(text="Делись!", request_contact=True)
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(button_phone)
    await message.answer(text="Для того, чтобы понять кто прислал чек, мне нужен твой номер", reply_markup=keyboard)
    # await WaitPhoto.waiting_photo.set()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
async def contact_photo(pic2: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = pic2.contact
    phone = str(data)
    phone = re.findall('"phone_number": "[0-9]+"', phone)
    phone = str(phone).replace('"phone_number": "', '+')
    # global phone = phone
    phone = phone.replace('"', '')
    await state.update_data(phone=phone)
    userbtn = str(data)
    userbtn = re.findall('"user_id": [0-9]+', userbtn)
    userbtn = str(userbtn).replace('"user_id": ', '')
    add_to_dict(userbtn, phone)
    message = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Чайная История на Пушке", callback_data='Чайная История на Пушке фото'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Чайная История на Театралке',
                                          callback_data='Чайная История на Театралке фото')]
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*message)
    # await WaitPhoto.next()
    await bot.send_message(pic2.chat.id, "Выбери свою точку", reply_markup=keyboard)
#
#
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='Чайная История на Пушке фото')
async def send_long_message_from(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # inf = pic2
    inf = 1
    file_id, phone = await state.get_data()
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=chekichat, photo= file_id)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chekichat, text=f"Хей,сегодня {a}, отправил его {phone} и это {inf}")
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: @oleksandrigo неотсылает сообщение

Comment: Какой именно хендлер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал все без FSM, передачей значения в списке списка

```
#Оброаботка присылаемого сообщения
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
async def photo_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global file_id
    file_id = [message.photo[-1].file_id]  # file ID загруженной фотографии
    await state.update_data(file_id=file_id)
    # print(type(file_id))
    # file_id1 = pic.photo
    button_phone = types.KeyboardButton(text="Делись!", request_contact=True)
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(button_phone)
    await message.answer(text="Для того, чтобы понять кто прислал чек, мне нужен твой номер", reply_markup=keyboard)
    # await WaitPhoto.waiting_photo.set()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
async def contact_photo(pic2: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # file_id.download('data/send-' + pic2.photo[-1].file_unique_id + '.jpg')
    data = pic2.contact
    phone = str(data)
    phone = re.findall('"phone_number": "[0-9]+"', phone)
    phone = str(phone).replace('"phone_number": "', '+')
    phone = phone.replace('"', '')
    global phone1
    phone1 = phone
    await state.update_data(phone=phone)
    userbtn = str(data)
    userbtn = re.findall('"user_id": [0-9]+', userbtn)
    userbtn = str(userbtn).replace('"user_id": ', '')
    add_to_dict(userbtn, phone)
    message = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Чайная История на Пушке", callback_data='Чайная История на Пушке фото'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Чайная История на Театралке',
                                          callback_data='Чайная История на Театралке фото')]
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*message)
    # await WaitPhoto.next()
    await bot.send_message(pic2.chat.id, "Выбери свою точку", reply_markup=keyboard)
    # await pic2.answer("", reply_markup=None)
#
#
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='Чайная История на Пушке фото')
async def send_long_message_from(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    a = datetime.date.today()
    # print(file_id, 'pop1')
    # print(file_id[0])
    await file_id[0].download(f'cheki/send-{file_id[0].file_unique_id}.jpg')  # Сохраниение чеков
    inf = 'Чайная История на Пушке'
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=chekichat, photo=file_id[0])
    file_id.clear()
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chekichat, text=f"Хей,сегодня {a}, отправил его {phone1} и это {inf}")


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='Чайная История на Театралке фото')
async def send_long_message_from(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    a = datetime.date.today()
    # print(file_id, 'pop2')
    # print(file_id[0])
    await file_id[0].download(f'cheki/send-{file_id[0].file_unique_id}.jpg')  # Сохраниение чеков
    inf = 'Чайная История на Театралке'
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=chekichat, photo=file_id[0])
    file_id.clear()
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chekichat, text=f"Хей,сегодня {a}, отправил его {phone1} и это {inf}")
```